# String arrays using Scanner

Tags: java, arrays, string, java.util.scanner

In my program I need to create an array of strings which will allow the user to type out upto 100 strings of text one after the other in the console, using scanner. I then need the program to be able to display all the strings typed (<=100) when the user types the word 'stop'.

I'm not expecting anyone to write the whole program for me but maybe just some tips?

I'm sure this is pretty basic but I'm very new to java and I cannot fail this module, any help is massively appreciated!

```
package assignment2017;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class FootballResultsGenerator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {



        String m = (" : ");
        String promptA = ("Goals scored by: ");
        String resultA = ("Results: ");
        String awayTeamGoals = ("the away teams scored: ");
        String homeTeamGoals = ("the home teams scored: "); 
        String totalGoals = ("Total number of goals: ");

                int numberOfGames=0;

                String lineSplit = ("-------------------------------------------");
        //These are my teams.

        //home
        String ah = ("Tottenham Hotspur(Home)");
        String gh = ("Sunderland(Home)");
        String ch = ("Manchester City(Home)");
        String ih = ("Everton(Home)");
        String eh = ("Liverpool(Home)");
        String bh = ("Arsenal(Home)");
        String dh = ("Manchester United(Home)");
        String fh = ("Chelsea(Home)");
        String hh = ("West Bromwich(Home)");
        String jh = ("Stoke city(Home)");
        //away
        String ba = ("Arsenal(Away)");
        String da = ("Manchester United(Away)");
        String fa = ("Chelsea(Away)");
        String ha = ("West Bromwich(Away)");
        String ja = ("Stoke city(Away)");
        String aa = ("Tottenham Hotspur(Away)");
        String ga = ("Sunderland(Away)");
        String ca = ("Manchester City(Away)");
        String ia = ("Everton(Away)");
        String ea = ("Liverpool(Away)");

        System.out.println("Football results generator");

        System.out.println(lineSplit);

        //Tottenham
        System.out.println (ah + " vs " + ba);
        System.out.println(lineSplit);
        numberOfGames++;
        System.out.println("    -" + promptA + ah);
        //scanner
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int inputAH = scan.nextInt(); 


        //Arsenal
        System.out.println("    -" + promptA + ba);
        int inputBA = scan.nextInt(); 

        System.out.println ();
        System.out.println (ch + " vs " + da);
        System.out.println(lineSplit);
        numberOfGames++;
        //Man city
        System.out.println("    -" + promptA + ch);
        int inputCH = scan.nextInt(); 

        //Liverpool
        System.out.println("    -" + promptA + da);
        int inputDA = scan.nextInt(); 

        System.out.println ();
        System.out.println (eh + " vs " + fa);
        System.out.println(lineSplit);
        numberOfGames++;
        //chelsea

        System.out.println("    -" + promptA + eh);
        int inputEH = scan.nextInt(); 

        //sunderland

        System.out.println("    -" + promptA + fa);
        int inputFA = scan.nextInt(); 

        System.out.println ();
        System.out.println (gh + " vs " + ha);
        System.out.println(lineSplit);
        numberOfGames++;
        //West brom

        System.out.println("    -" + promptA + gh);
        int inputGH = scan.nextInt(); 

        //Everton

        System.out.println("    -" + promptA + ha);
        int inputHA = scan.nextInt(); 

        System.out.println ();
        System.out.println (ih + " vs " + ja);
        System.out.println(lineSplit);
        numberOfGames++;
        //Stoke

        System.out.println("    -" + promptA + ih);
        int inputIH = scan.nextInt(); 

        //

        System.out.println("    -" + promptA + ja);
        int inputJA = scan.nextInt(); 

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////// second set of games
        System.out.println (aa + " vs " + bh);
        System.out.println(lineSplit);
        numberOfGames++;

        System.out.println("    -" + promptA + aa);
        int inputAA = scan.nextInt(); 

        System.out.println("    -" + promptA + bh);
        int inputBH = scan.nextInt(); 

        System.out.println (ca + " vs " + dh);
        System.out.println(lineSplit);
        numberOfGames++;

        System.out.println("    -" + promptA + ca);
        int inputCA = scan.nextInt(); 

        System.out.println("    -" + promptA + dh);
        int inputDH = scan.nextInt(); 

        System.out.println (ea + " vs " + hh);
        System.out.println(lineSplit);
        numberOfGames++;

        System.out.println("    -" + promptA + ea);
        int inputEA = scan.nextInt(); 

        System.out.println("    -" + promptA + hh);
        int inputHH = scan.nextInt(); 

        System.out.println (jh + " vs " + ga);
        System.out.println(lineSplit);
        numberOfGames++;

        System.out.println("    -" + promptA + jh);
        int inputJH = scan.nextInt(); 

        System.out.println("    -" + promptA + ga);
        int inputGA = scan.nextInt(); 

        System.out.println (ia + " vs " + fh);
        System.out.println(lineSplit);
        numberOfGames++;

        System.out.println("    -" + promptA + ia);
        int inputIA = scan.nextInt(); 

        System.out.println("    -" + promptA + fh);
        int inputFH = scan.nextInt(); 

        //Goals scored in total

        int goalint = (inputAH + inputCH + inputEH + inputGH +inputIH + inputBA + inputDA + inputFA + inputHA +inputJA);

        //Full results array
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(lineSplit);
        System.out.println( resultA);
        System.out.println(lineSplit);
        System.out.println();
        //first Set Of Games
        System.out.println(ah + m + ba + m + inputAH + m +inputBA);
        System.out.println(ch + m + da + m + inputCH + m + inputDA);
        System.out.println(eh + m + fa + m + inputEH + m + inputFA);
        System.out.println(gh + m + ha + m + inputGH + m + inputHA);
        System.out.println(ih + m + ja + m + inputIH + m + inputJA);
        //second set of games
        System.out.println(bh + m + aa + m + inputBH + m + inputAA);
        System.out.println(dh + m + ca + m + inputDH + m + inputCA);
        System.out.println(hh + m + ea + m + inputHH + m + inputEA);
        System.out.println(jh + m + ga + m + inputJH + m + inputGA);
        System.out.println(fh + m + ia + m + inputFH + m + inputIA);

        System.out.println();
        // Goals scored...
        System.out.println(lineSplit);
        System.out.println(totalGoals + goalint);
        System.out.println(homeTeamGoals + (inputAH + inputCH + inputEH + inputGH +inputIH) + " goals.");
        System.out.println(awayTeamGoals + (inputBA + inputDA + inputFA + inputHA +inputJA) + " goals.");
        // total number of matches
        System.out.println("Number of games: " +numberOfGames);

        //stop
        String username = ("stop");
        String userName = ("Stop");

        System.exit(0);

    }}
```

Comment: Have you already tried something you can show us?

Comment: Share what have you tried until now

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope this helps!

```
String[] array = new String[100];
String str = null;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {       
    str= sc.nextLine();
    if(str.equals("stop")) {
        break;
    }
    array[i] = str;
}
```

Comment: This is actually very helpful! Is there a way I can make it so when I type 'stop' the previous array inputs are displayed? Thanks so much!

Comment: @JHurst You cannot expect anyone to spoon feed you! [Read this](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-print-an-array/) .